# Drools KieBuilder.buildAll() and AbstractKieProject.verify() is too slow

Tags: performance, drools

I have xls file with 500 rules.
When I call `KieService.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll()` it takes more then 2 minutes.
Much time is spent on `PomModel.init()` and `KieModuleKieProject.verify(ResultImpl)`.

It's very slow. How can I workaround it (it's beter without depricated methods/classes)?

My code is from drools examples and looks like this:

```
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("MyRules.xls"));

    KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kb.buildAll();
    KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
    KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());

    kContainer.newKieSession();
```

Comment: I am kind of observing the same behaviour. You had any luck in finding a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It slows down due to ParseTools.findClass (mvel2). It tryes to find element of a rule in ContextClassLoader. In my case ClassLoader has very much classes and it slows down a performance.